# Superpowered native functions not available at runtime

Tags: android, linker

I have got the cross example into Android Studio 2.0

I get a successful build and deploy to an android device but the moment it runs it fails as the java main activity can't find the native methods built in the example cpp file. The cpp is building correctly.

```
                                                                          java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.clayteq.audiosupertest.MainActivity.SuperpoweredExample(java.lang.String, long[]) (tried Java_com_clayteq_audiosupertest_MainActivity_SuperpoweredExample and Java_com_clayteq_audiosupertest_MainActivity_SuperpoweredExample__Ljava_lang_String_2_3J)
                                                                            at com.clayteq.audiosupertest.MainActivity.SuperpoweredExample(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.clayteq.audiosupertest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)``
```

I'm missing something somewhere! It appears that the object from the cpp operation is not being included.

Answer (score 2):

The superpowered installation examples on the github pages fall a little short if you are new to native development!

The .cpp file includes sections to export it's methods with qualified java package names.

As I'd built my project under my own package the packages exported from the cpp link were obviously a mismatch.

Scan the .cpp file for JNIEXPORT instances and make the exported classes match your java package name!

( Why is it that after a day of 'learning curve' you post to Stackoverflow and then find the answer just minutes afterward? )